# pgfplots height=, what is it good for?

Tags: pgfplots, height, size

My understanding of the `height=` key was that that would fix the height of the plot and the `y=` value would be adjust accordingly. But, that does not appear to be the case.

Both plots below have `height=5cm` specified and I have controlled the `ytick=` and `yticklabels=` to ensure that those do not effect the total height but, still there is a noticable difference in the heights:

[image]

I don't think this is a rounding issue as I can compute the `y=` value manually and things work just fine:

[image]

### Question:

- If there is something wrong with my thinking of how the `height=` key is supposed to work, how can I automate the compution of the `y=` value based on the `height=`, `ymax=` and `ymin` keys so that I can achieve the output of the second test case but not have to manualy compute the `y=` before doing the plot.

### Code: `height=`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}{%
    \draw [black]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=2.1,
        ytick={1},%         Ensure that the y ticks and labels are
        yticklabels={1},%   NOT effecting the height of the plot
        height=5cm,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:3, ultra thick, blue]{0.5};
    \end{axis}
    \DrawBoundingBox%
\end{tikzpicture}
~%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=5.5,
        ytick={1},%         Ensure that the y ticks and labels are
        yticklabels={1},%   NOT effecting the height of the plot
        height=5cm,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:3, ultra thick, red]{4.25};
    \end{axis}
    \DrawBoundingBox%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code Used Computed `y=`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}{%
    \draw [black]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
}

\newlength{\PlotY}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlength{\PlotY}{5cm/3.1}%  3.1 = ymax - ymin = 2 - (-1)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=2.1,
        ytick={1},%         Ensure that the y ticks and labels are
        yticklabels={1},%   NOT effecting the height of the plot
        y=\PlotY,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:3, ultra thick, blue]{0.5};
    \end{axis}
    \DrawBoundingBox%
\end{tikzpicture}
~%
\pgfmathsetlength{\PlotY}{5cm/6.5}% 6.5 = ymax - ymin = 5.5 - (-1)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=5.5,
        ytick={1},%         Ensure that the y ticks and labels are
        yticklabels={1},%   NOT effecting the height of the plot
        y=\PlotY,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:3, ultra thick, red]{4.25};
    \end{axis}
    \DrawBoundingBox%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This somehow seems to be caused by the option `axis lines=middle`. If you remove that key, or if you set `axis lines*=middle` to remove the arrowhead, the plots have the same size.

Comment: Also try `scale only axis` (page 293)

Comment: @JohnKormylo: That seems to work.

Comment: The difference in height is caused by the xticklabels I believe. The y-axes have approximately the same length (0.004pt difference), but the xticklabel nodes go a bit below the bottom of the y-axis in the second example, extending the bounding box. `scale only axis`  works because this makes the axis longer, which in turn means that the xticklabels do not extend the bounding box. `axis lines*=middle` works because without the `*` the ticklabels are shifted down a bit, so they don't cover the ticks themselves.

Comment: Your second version works for the same reason, there is room for the xticklabels.  But if you do the same thing that `pgfplots` does (assuming  `scale only axis` is not used), i.e. `\pgfmathsetlength{\PlotY}{(5cm-45pt)/6.5}`, you get the same problem there, for the same reason. Add `xticklabel style={draw}` to more easily see why the ticklabels cause the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First take into account this quote from the `pgfplots` manual (section 4.10.1 *Common scaling options*):

> Please note that pgfplots only estimates the size needed for axis- and tick labels. The estimate
>   assumes a fixed amount of space for anything which is outside of the axis box. This has the effect that
>   the final images may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than the prescribed dimensions. However, the
>   fixed amount is always the same; it is set to 45pt. That means that multiple pictures with the same
>   target dimensions will have the same size for their axis boxes – even if the size for descriptions varies.

Hence, in your first case `pgfplots` will set the y unit so that the height of the y-axis (only the axis box, not including descriptions) is 5cm - 45pt = 97.26pt. In your second case you've set the y unit so that the height is 5cm = 142.26pt.

Now, let's add `xticklabel style={draw}` and see what the output is for the second `tikzpicture` (the tallest one), with various settings:

1. Your first case:

   [image]

   Note the nodes of the xticklabels protrude slightly below the bottom of the y-axis. This does obviously not happen for the first `tikzpicture`, where `ymax=2.1`. As a result, the bounding box of the second `tikzpicture` is extended a little bit, compared to the first one.
2. With `axis lines*=middle`:

   [image]

   Note that the ticks are only on the inside of the axis, and ticklabels are not shifted down due to the ticks. Hence, the labels no longer go below the y-axis.
3. With `scale only axis`, or your `y=\PlotY`:

   [image]

   Because the entire y-axis is 45pt longer, the part below 0 is also longer, and there is room for the ticklabels.
4. With `\pgfmathsetlength{\PlotY}{(5cm-45)/6.5}`, corresponding to what `pgfplots` does:

   [image]
5. Your first case, but with `ymin=-1.2` instead of `ymin=-1`:

   [image]

   Because a larger fraction of the y-axis is below 0, the distance (in `pt`) from y=0 to the bottom of the y-axis is longer, and thus there is room for the ticklabels.

I think to sum up, one could say that the cause of the problem is a combination of several factors, such as

- the total height of the ticklabel nodes
- the height of the axis
- the axis limits
- tick position

When these interact such that the ticklabel nodes extend the bounding box in one case, but not the other, you get a difference in height of the `tikzpicture`s.

So what do you do? I guess as long as you're using `axis lines=middle` you have to somehow make sure that the part of the y-axis below 0 is long enough that you will have room for the ticklabels. Another possible method would be to add the `overlay` option to the ticklabel nodes, so they don't influence the bounding box, and then use something similar to your `\DrawBoundingBox` macro to set bounding box manually. I don't have any good ideas at the moment though.

---

Aside: You might note that the node for the `-2` ticklabel is larger than that for `2`. You could for example use the `typeset ticklabels with strut` option if you want to avoid that. That will increase the total height of the nodes quite a bit, so one could consider `inner ysep=0` in addition.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't occur to me that `-2` and `2` would have different heights. That definltey explains this result and I think the solutions of using a `strut`, `axis lines*=` or `scale only axis=true` are adequate.  Using `typeset ticklabels with strut` will only work if y-axis ends _above_ the labels in _both_ cases.  If the labels are _below_ the ticklabels in _both_ cases then the `\strut` won't have any effect. If one of the y-axis is _below_ and the other _above_ then the `\strut` won't help.

Comment: @PeterGrill The difference between `-2` and `2` is *not* directly the cause of the problem, if that was what you meant, the `2` also goes below the y-axis. It does increase the problem though, but `typeset ticklabels with strut` will further increase the problem, as it increases the depth of the nodes a lot. But I didn't intend the strut business as a solution to the problem (it's not), that was just a side note.

Comment: Not sure I understand the first part of your comment. The difference in height between `-2` and `2` was the cause of the problem when the `ymin` was such that the `-2` was below `ymin` and `2` was above `ymin`. Agreed with the second part. I think you can remove `partial answer` text from you answer as I think you have covered it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Well yes, but that wasn't the case here, both were below, and it's a bit too simple anyway. I mean, the cause is that *the combination of* i) the total height of the ticklabel nodes, ii) the height of the axis,  iii) the axis limits and iv) tick position is such that the ticklabel nodes extend the bounding box in one case, but not the other.