# Truncation of a graph line

Tags: pgfplots

What can be done in the MWE below to prevent the truncation of the graph line at the top of the bell curve?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3, 
samples=100,
ymin=0,
axis lines=left, % This creates the truncation
hide y axis, % Has no impact
]

\addplot [very thick] {gauss(x, 0, 1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If `axis lines=left` is removed, it also removes the truncation.

[image: zoomed in] [image: full graph]

Comment: So, which axis lines do you want?

Comment: As in the MWE. The comment re Y axis is just for a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `clip=false`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3, 
samples=100,
ymin=0,clip=false, %<-added
axis lines=left, % This creates the truncation
hide y axis, % Has no impact
]

\addplot [very thick] {gauss(x, 0, 1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am also wondering if [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427334/121799) is related.